# Row in table show and disappear

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

When I click on the button row will show on less than one second and disappear. Everything will be ok, when I delete form tag. Why? What should I do to don't must delete form tag?

Here is code

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table id="myTable">
          <tr>
            <td>Row1 cell1</td>
            <td>Row1 cell2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Row2 cell1</td>
            <td>Row2 cell2</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Row3 cell1</td>
            <td>Row3 cell2</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <br>

        <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

        <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
            var row = table.insertRow(0);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
            cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
        }
        </script>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button is causing your page to submit, which refreshes it without the new row.

Try:

```
<button onclick="myFunction(); return false;">Try it</button>
```

to prevent the submit ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bobdye/yd6zyu6h/)).